# Pasar el ID de usuario entre pantallas y utilizarlo

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

Tengo un login que me devuelve el UserID, y lo envío por medio de una ruta como la siguiente: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/QueryRecordScreenUser', arguments: {'UserID': 1});`, el problema es el siguiente: Quiero usar ese UserID para cargar información de internet, la función es la siguiente:

```
Future<QueryRecord> fetchQueryRecord() async {
  final finaluserid = 1; //AQUI DEBERÍA IR EL UserID proporcionado por la ruta.

  //Los siguientes, son los parámetros utilizados para cargar un registro.
  var UserID = finaluserid;
  var RecordTypeID = 1;
  var RecordDate = "2022-04-29";
  var s = UserID.toString() + "/" + RecordDate + "/" + RecordTypeID.toString();

//http request GET
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://a199-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/record/$s'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return QueryRecord.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load record.');
  }
}
```

Llamo los datos dentro del widget principal, he impreso este valor en la consola y si imprime el valor deseado, he intentado enviar el `userid` al `Future<QueryRecord>`, sin éxito.

```
      Map? args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map?;
      int userid = args!["UserID"];
```

Anexo el código completo:

```
class QueryRecordsScreenUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const QueryRecordsScreenUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<QueryRecordsScreenUser> createState() => _QueryRecordsScreenUserState();
}
class _QueryRecordsScreenUserState extends State<QueryRecordsScreenUser> {
  late Future<QueryRecord> futureQueryRecord;
  DateTime valueRegistro = DateTime.parse('0000-00-00');
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final firstDate = DateTime(2022, 2); //A partir de que fecha funciona el calendario
  final lastDate = DateTime.now(); //Hasta que fecha funciona el calendario
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureQueryRecord = fetchQueryRecord();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Map? args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map?;
      int userid = args!["UserID"];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('queryrecords.title').tr(),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: const []),
      body: Column(
          //BOTON DE GUARDAR CAMBIOS
          Row(
            children: [
              const Text('queryrecords.recentRecords',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                  .tr()
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          ),
          FutureBuilder<QueryRecord>(
            future: futureQueryRecord,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                          title: Text((convertirFecha(
                              snapshot.data!.recordDate))), //fecha del registro
                          trailing: Wrap(
                            spacing: 12, // space between two icons
                            children: <Widget>[
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_upward_outlined,
                                color: AppTheme.green,
                              ), // icon-1
                              Text(
                                ((convertirHora(snapshot.data!.entryTime))),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18), //hora de entrada
                              ),
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_downward_outlined,
                                color: AppTheme.red,
                              ), // icon-
                              
                              Text(
                                ((convertirHora(snapshot.data!.exitTime))),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18), 
                                    //hora de salida
                              )   
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    const DisplayRecordScreenUser()));          
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                debugPrint('El usuario es: ' + userid.toString());
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                
              }
            },
          )
          
        ],
        
      ),
      
    );
    
  }

Future<QueryRecord> fetchQueryRecord() async {
  // final userid = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
  final finaluserid = 1;
  //Los siguientes, son los parámetros utilizados para cargar un registro.
  var UserID = finaluserid;
  var RecordTypeID = 1;
  var RecordDate = "2022-04-29";
  var s = UserID.toString() + "/" + RecordDate + "/" + RecordTypeID.toString();

//http request GET
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://a199-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/record/$s'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return QueryRecord.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
    //El [0], es para ignorar que el json no tiene una cabecera tipo RECORD.
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load record.');
  }
}
```

Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia o solución, lo agradeceré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres guardar el id del usuario al momento de logearse para reutilizarlo en otras paginas es recomendable usar variables de usuario, por medio del package [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Una vez instalado el paquete, debes crear una clase con el nombre que tu desees, en mi caso como `UserPreferences`:

```
    class UserPreferences {
  String id = 'userId';

  saveUserId(int userId) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setInt(id, userId);
  }

  Future<int?> getUserId() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = preferences.getInt(id);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Para guardar el id, al momento de logearte deberás llamar a esta función (setUserId) y le pasas como parámetro el id del usuario.

Para poder consultar este valor en distintas clases, lo puedes hacer por medio de un `FutureBuilder` o en el initState llamas a una función que al incializarte la pantalla te asigne a una variable este valor, pero vamos a continuar con tu ejemplo:

```
    Future<QueryRecord> fetchQueryRecord() async {
        //Aqui creas una instancia de la clase UserPreferences 
        UserPreferences userPreferences = UserPreferences();
        //Consultas el dato almacenado y la asignas a la variable userId
        final userId = await userPreferences.getUserId();
       
        final finaluserid = userId;
        
        var UserID = finaluserid;
        var RecordTypeID = 1;
        var RecordDate = "2022-04-29";
        var s =
            UserID.toString() + "/" + RecordDate + "/" + RecordTypeID.toString();
    
    
        final response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse('https://a199-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/record/$s'));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return QueryRecord.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
         
        } else {
          throw Exception('Failed to load record.');
        }
      }
```

Espero y mi respuesta te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho, tengo la implementación de esto en mi proyecto, pero falta hacer las pruebas, pero quería tener una forma diferente para hacer otras pruebas, pero eso lo dejaré para otra pregunta.